# How can I have facebook Thumnail for pictures in forum

Tags: facebook, mybb

I have a forum that made it by [MYBB](http://Mybb.com) system and every photo in every post of my Forum just shown for **Registered User**, and when I share it in Facebook it doesn't show post photo in thumbnail!!
I want to know how can I register Facebook Crawler for this kind of thumbnail ?? or is there any way to make it shown for Facebook??

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Add the Open Graph meta tags to your pages (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ )
2. Ensure that the tags are available to Facebook's crawler (which won't be logged in to your site),
3. Check what facebook is detecting on your page using the debug tool ( http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug )

Comment: I did theme but again I have this problem
when I deactivate the Obligation of showing pic just register user it work good but I want it work with obligation too??

Comment: You'd have to change your code to allow Facebook's crawler to access the meta tags, even if regular users must log in - i can't help with that though as it depends on how your access control works

Comment: do you User Agent String of facebook??